# What is the difference between Android location manger, Google play services location, Google Maps geolocation API to get current location?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-play-services, locationmanager

I found that

```
Android’s Location Manager API
Google Play Services Location APIs
Google Maps Geolocation API
```

can get current location, what is the difference between them?

Especially Google Maps Geolocation API is not free, why should one use that instead of free ones?

Maybe Android's location Manager and Google play service location is only available to Android device, while Google Maps Geolocation works both on Android and iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience with what you're talking about, but I did some research about differences these technologies and maybe it can help you:

"Google Maps Geolocation API" unlike Android's Location Manager API, can work in web browsers as well as the Android operating system. And Google Play Services Location API is mostly used by mobile app developers to gather information about verified users.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).